# NetSuite: Cannot access object inside object type from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, netsuite

I am trying to return only object list from an array of object of below format using restlet.

```
{
    "recordType": "inventoryitem",
    "id": "387",
    "values": {
        "itemid": "ACC00001",
        "displayname": "400 Watt Power Supply",
        "salesdescription": "400 Watt Power Supply",
        "baseprice": "109.00"
    }
}
```

From this array, I want to access/return "values". When I return the whole array I can get it on Postman. When I return the only arrResults[0].id,i can get the value but when i try to access arrResults[0].values I cannot access it. When I log its value it is undefined.

I think on normal js it should have worked. Is there a different way we do it in NetSuite part.

Comment: if you console.log(arrResults[0]) ?

Comment: yes, I can get the above object if I log the arrResults[0]. and also value of arrResults[0].id and arrResults[0].recordType

Comment: Try logging `JSON.stringify(arrResults[0].values)`.

Comment: @krypton Still undefined

Comment: Can you show the code on how arrResults is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you are trying to access the key/value pairs in the "values" object?
and if that is the case this snippet example may work for you:

```
    var newObj = originalObj["values"];
          for(var fieldname in newObj){
            var value = newObj[fieldname];
               console.log( "Record fieldname:"+fieldname+" and Value: " + value );

            }
```